# I am using Eclipse IDE. I want to use clip to play a .wav file. But when I click on Run, I always got <terminated> at Console window

Tags: java, eclipse, wav, javasound

```
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
    import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

    public class Test13 {

        public Test13() {

            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            System.out.println(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav"));

            try{
              Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
              AudioInputStream inputStream = 
                   AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav"));
              clip.open(inputStream);
              clip.start();
              clip.close();
            } catch (Exception  e)
                {
                  System.out.println("something failed");
                }
     } 
}
```

//When I click on Run, at Console window there showed :

```
//<terminated> Test13 [java application]C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: you don't have a main method in your class, so you don't have an entry point. what are you trying to run?

Comment: `clip.start()` just starts the audio playing, you have to wait for it to finish some time later. `clip.close()` does not wait.